# How to block every port except specific ones to a user with iptables?

Tags: linux, iptables, port

I'd like to block every port except 80, 443, 1005 to a specific user (owner) with iptables.

What command should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "owner" match. For example:

> iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -m owner --uid-owner nikesh  -j ACCEPT

Read more: http://linuxpoison.blogspot.it/2010/11/how-to-limit-network-access-by-user.html#ixzz3UOJ2glqS

Anyway, a simple google for "iptables match owner" will return plenty of results. Please to you own research before posting questions.

**UPDATE**
To block every port, you have two different options.

**1. Change the chain policy.** As an example, for INPUT chain:

> iptables -P INPUT REJECT

**2. Leave chain policy to default (ACCEPT) but create a last-matching rule to deny all traffic.** Example:

> iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT

**After that, you can re-enable the ports required by issuing multiple ACCEPT rules.** For example:

> iptables -I INPUT 1 -m owner --dport 80 --uid-owner nikesh  -j ACCEPT
>   iptables -I INPUT 1 -m owner --dport 443 --uid-owner nikesh  -j ACCEPT
>   iptables -I INPUT 1 -m owner --dport 1005 --uid-owner nikesh  -j ACCEPT

These are examples only. Take you time to planning your ruleset. And, above all, ***READ IPTABLES MAN PAGE***. Trying to configure any critical service (as a network firewall) without reading the manual is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Thank you, but I already know the "-m owner --uid-owner owner" parameter. My question was mainly how to block every port except three. I got locked out of my server twice and I'm just seeking advice before locking myself out a third time. I never used iptables before.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. But when I execute those functions, it returns me this error:

x_tables: ip_tables: owner match: used from hooks INPUT, but only valid from OUTPUT/POSTROUTING

Do you know any workaround?

Comment: There is no workaround for this message. After all, in the INPUT table (when the packets enter the netfilter path) the system does NOT know who generated the packets (after all, how can it understand who generated the packet on a remote system?). Maybe the POSTROUTING table can be used for your scopes...